# How do I achieve an in-place sort on a sub range of elements in an Array<T> in swift?

Tags: swift, sorting, copy-on-write

The standard sort methods for the Array type does not have a variant in which the region of the array to be sorted can be narrowed. Using an ArraySlice does not result in the original data getting sorted due to the copy-on-write semantics.

Do I have to write a new sort implementation to achieve an in-place sort on a subrange of an Array? Or is there an ugly way to create a second Array that aliases the desired element range from the original array?

Comment: You can write `array[from...to].sort()`, but I *assume* that that creates a temporary copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [subscript operation that takes a range](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection/2965317-subscript) returns a mutable value. If you directly invoke a mutating method on it, it will mutate the original array in place:

```
var numbers = [3,5,2,4,1]
numbers[1..<4].sort()
print(numbers) // [3, 2, 4, 5, 1]
```

As of Swift 4.2, I *think* this is no more efficient than making a temporary copy of the slice (Source: [forum post 1](https://forums.swift.org/t/additional-methods-for-removing-elements-from-a-collection-in-swift/6710/3), [forum post 2](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-is-substring-a-textoutputstream/12795/11). These posts talk about all kinds of slicing operations incl. ones that change the length of the source collection, but it should be the same for in-place sorting.)

There've been a lot of under the hood changes for the upcoming Swift 5 release that aim to make this more efficient (background: [ownership manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md)). In Swift 5, a setter (like a mutating subscript) can be modeled as a coroutine, which would allow to perform this kind of operation in place. But I'm not 100% sure if this will be the case in Swift 5.0.

Comment: I guess my question would: is that somehow less "space complex" (whatever that means) than what I said, or is it just cleaner semantics?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. I edited my answer to give some background info.

Comment: Cool, thanks, just wanted to clarify that (to the extent that we can do so).

Comment: If you want to know for sure, consider asking on the [Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org). That's where the people hang out who can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Well, the question is only whether this answer is open to the same "objection" from the OP as my answer.

Comment: It's interesting this code differs from "var subarray = numbers[1..<4]; subarray.sort()"

Comment: `Array`'s ranged subscript doesn't use `_modify` in Swift 5, and therefore the sorting is done out-of-place (I also tested w/ optimisations enabled, the SIL optimiser doesn't appear to do anything special to enable an in-place modification as `replaceSubrange` is still called).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't *believe* that `Array`'s ranged subscript can be easily modified to allow arbitrary in-place mutations. This is due to the fact that in order to do so, it must yield an `ArraySlice` that either has a unique and/or pinned reference to the underlying buffer. If it's a unique reference, there's nothing to stop the caller from deallocating it and passing back an `ArraySlice` that doesn't contain the rest of the buffer. If it's pinned, mutations of the `ArraySlice` that gets passed back will always be done in-place, thus losing value semantics.

Comment: So this is likely something that the SIL optimiser will have to pick up on (either that or `ArraySlice` needs to always hold onto the entire underlying buffer of elements).

Answer (score 1):

Hard to see what you think the problem is:

```
var arr = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
let range = 4...7
arr.replaceSubrange(range, with: arr[range].sorted())
print(arr) // [9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Was that not the intended goal?

Comment: Is this equivalent to copying out the sub range to new storage, sorting it, then copying it back? This would achieve the desired result, but not necessarily in the space complexity I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't know what space complexity is and it didn't seem to figure in your original question. `sorted`, and even `sort`, will make a copy no matter what you do; arrays are value types.

Comment: The temporary `arr[range].sorted()` is *Auxiliary Space* that will need to be created by this code.

Comment: @Carpsen90 But that's inevitable. It's a value type. The only sure way to avoid adding auxiliary space would be e.g. to implement a linked list yourself and repoint the links as desired.

Comment: @matt space complexity is the storage analog to the concept of runtime complexity.  An operation on an array that requires a full temporary copy would have linear space complexity, while one that does not (only requires temporary storage that is not related to the length of the original array) has constant space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a custom quicksort implementation:

```
// MARK: - Array<Element: Comparable>

extension Array where Element: Comparable {

    // MARK: - Internal

    mutating func quickSort(subrange: Range<Int>) {
        privateQuickSort(left: subrange.lowerBound, right: subrange.upperBound - 1)
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    mutating private func partition(left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        var i = left
        for j in (left + 1)..<(right + 1) {
            if self[j] < self[left] {
                i += 1
                (self[i], self[j]) = (self[j], self[i])
            }
        }
        (self[i], self[left]) = (self[left], self[i])
        return i
    }
    mutating private func privateQuickSort(left: Int, right: Int) {
        if right > left {
            let pivotIndex = partition(left: left, right: right)
            privateQuickSort(left: left, right: pivotIndex - 1)
            privateQuickSort(left: pivotIndex + 1, right: right)
        }
    }
}

var array = [10,0,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,3]

array.quickSort(subrange: 0..<array.count)
print(array)
```

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]

But for

```
var array = [10,0,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,3]

array.quickSort(subrange: 0..<2)
```

> [0, 10, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3]

Original quicksort swift algorithm [source](https://gist.github.com/fjcaetano/b0c00a889dc2a17efad9)